# How to add the output of failing NUnit tests to the TFS build report?

Tags: tfs, nunit, tfsbuild

I need to include the output of my failing tests (NUnit) on the final build report of TFS.

I've looked around and found [solutions](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/48af7659-f67b-454a-9042-7307d028485b/tfs-vstudio-2013-how-can-i-see-testcontext-output-from-build-definition?forum=tfsbuild) for VSTest, but not NUnit unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can edit the build process template xaml you use and add a custom task. https://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20integrate%20the%20nUnit%20build%20activity&referringTitle=Documentation

Alternatively (and arguably worse, but it's what I do) is to not modify the template xaml but to target a custom msbuild file (.proj) into which I'd run the nunit tasks. You then get your build def to build this .proj rather that a sln and it's this that runs and outputs your nunit results.